# C# also gives Double Folded Array Leash

Tags: c#, arrays

```
        int[] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4,5 };
            int[] y = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
            int[,] s=new int[(x.Length)*(x.Length),2];
       
         for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < y.Length; i++)
                {
                    s[i, j] = x[i] * y[j];
                    Console.WriteLine(x[i] + " * " + y[j] + " = " + s[i, j]);
                }
            }
```

IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

It gives a memory error, but it says it hangs the memory of the variable, but I transfer more than the field of the series. I couldn't figure out what the problem was. Can you help?

Comment: you define s with `new int[..., 2]` and then access with `s[i,j]` - do you see the problem?

Comment: You have `i++` in inner loop, but it should be `j++`. Also, instead of `(x.Length)*(x.Length), 2` it should be `x.Length, y.Length`.

Comment: While all of the above may help you: This is a perfect time to learn how to debug. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Change:

```cs
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < y.Length; i++)
```

To:

```cs
    for (int i = 0; i <= x.Length-1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= y.Length-1; j++)
```

Also this line:

```cs
int[,] s=new int[(x.Length)*(x.Length),2];
```

Although no big problems but if x[] and y[] are different lengths might cause issues with storing i,j values. Did you mean to declare like :=

```cs
int[,] s=new int[(x.Length)*(y.Length),2];
```